# Conserved current of $O(N)$ vector model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem, higher-spin

I was reading a paper by Klebanov and Polyakov, Phys.Lett. B550 (2002) 213, (hep-th/0210114). In the paper, where they are discussing free O(N) vector models, they state that the theory has a class of conserved current with one conserved current for each spin. But I could not figure out how one derives the form of this conserved current and also, how the spin indices come to play a role in the expression.

Please clarify this matter.

> ...The simplest such $O(N)$ invariant theory is free: $$S=\frac{1}{2}\int d^3 x \sum^N_{a=1}(\partial_\mu \phi^a)^2\tag{3}$$
>   This theory has a class of $O(N)$ singlet conserved currents $$J_{(\mu_1 ... \mu_s)}=\phi^a\partial_{(\mu_1}...\partial_{\mu_s)}\phi^a+...\tag{4}$$